# After including a JS file in my Magento 2 custom widget, i m getting $. is undefined

Tags: magento2, jquery, widget

I have created a custom widget that requires **jQuery** code.

I have included the js file but when I'm trying to view the changes in the frontend, I'm getting jquery error.

I tried including the file in the footer.

Still, getting jquery error. `$. is undefined`.

I'm using default luma theme

Comment: Add your JS code in question.

Comment: Can you share error screen-shoot or code?

Comment: Did you use **requireJs** to add this JS in your code?
Check: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#extend_js_widget